# How to optimize this random entropy calculation for a large number of iterations?

Tags: arrays, random, julia

## What my code is trying to do :

I have an initial array containing an arrangement of molecules, each in a cell and confined to moving in a 2D array ( Up Down Left Right ) ( Array size:200x200 ). At each step I take a *random* molecule, and move it into a *random* adjacent cell.

Starting from a certain number and every few iterations, I calculate the entropy of this grid. The grid is cut into small squares of 25x25. I then use the Shannon entropy to calculate the entropy of the system.

## Objective:

Doing 1e8+ iterations in a decent time using an i5-6500, no GPU.

### My code:

```
function advance_multi_lattice(grid)   #Find the next state of the system

    rnd=rand(1:count(!iszero,grid))        #Random number to be used for a random molecule.
    slots=find(!iszero,grid)    #Cells containing molecules.
    chosen_slot=find(!iszero,grid)[rnd]    #Random cell. May contain multiple molecules.
    dim=size(grid)[1]    #Need this for rnd=3,4 later.  
    grid[chosen_slot]-=1    #Remove the molecules from the cell
    rnd_arr=[1,2,3,4]     #Array to random from.


    while true


        rnd=rand(rnd_arr)   #Random number to see which side should the molecules go.

        if rnd==1    #Right for example.
            try     #In case moving right is impossible, ie: moving right gets the molecule out. Remove 1 from rnd_arr and repeat.
                grid[chosen_slot+1]+=1
                break
            catch
                filter!(e->e!=1,rnd_arr)
            end
        elseif rnd==2
            try   #Same
                grid[chosen_slot-1]+=1
                break
            catch
                filter!(e->e!=2,rnd_arr)
            end
        #Repeat for the other numbers : 3 and 4...
    return Grid
end

function S(P)   #Entropy, if no molecules then return 0.
    s=[]
    for k in P
        if k==0
            push!(s,0)
        else
            push!(s,-k*log(k))
        end

    end
    return s
end

function find_molecules(grid) #How many molecules in the array
    s=0

    for slot in grid
        s+=slot
    end
    return s
end

function entropy_scale(grid,total_molecules)    #Calculate the entropy of the grid.
    P_array=Array{Float64}([])
    for i=1:8
        for j=1:8
            push!(P_array,find_molecules(grid[(i-1)*25+1:i*25,(j-1)*25+1:j*25]))
        end
    end

    P_array=P_array./total_molecules

    return sum(S(P_array))
end

function entropy_evolution(grid,n)    #The loop function. Changes the grid and returns the entropy as a function of steps.
    t_arr=Array{Int64}([])
    S_arr=Array{Float64}([])
    p=Progress(Int(n))    #Progress bar, using ProgressMeter.
    total_molecules=find_molecules(grid)
    for k=1:1e3
        grid=advance_multi_lattice(grid)

        next!(p)
    end

    for k=1e3+1:n
        grid=advance_multi_lattice(grid)

        if  k%500==0  #Only record entropy every 500 steps
            push!(S_arr,entropy_scale(grid,totel_molecules))
        end
        next!(p)
    end

    return S_arr,grid

end
```

### Results for my code :

For 1e5 iterations, I get 43 seconds. Which means that if I want an interesting result ( 1e9+ ), I need a lot of time, upwards to 1hour+. Changing the entropy calculation threshold barely scratches the performance unless it's really small.

Comment: Scanning the code I stumbled upon this:1) The Array s=[] runs faster if it's not an Abstract Array -> s=Float64[]. 2) There are 2 Arrays (probably a type mismatch) called: "grid" the other "Grid" in the code. 3) I copy-pasted the code and got 2 missing "end" in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are working under Julia 1.0 (for Julia 0.6 a small change is needed - I noted it in the code).

In order to improve the performance you should keep a vector of molecules - not a grid (you do not need it as you allow molecules to occupy the same location).

We will encode location of a molecule as a tuple `(x,y)`. Now you need a function that randomly moves one molecule. Here is how you can implement it (I hard coded the boundaries but of course you could change them to be a parameter):

```
function move_molecule((x,y)) # in Julia 0.6 it should be move_molecule(t)
    # and here in Julia 0.6 you should add: x, y = t
    if x == 1
        if y == 1
            ((1,2), (2,1))[rand(1:2)]
        elseif y == 200
            ((1,199), (2,200))[rand(1:2)]
        else
            ((2,y), (1,y-1), (1, y+1))[rand(1:3)]
        end
    elseif x == 200
        if y == 1
            ((200,2), (199,1))[rand(1:2)]
        elseif y == 200
            ((200,199), (199,200))[rand(1:2)]
        else
            ((200,y), (200,y-1), (200, y+1))[rand(1:3)]
        end
    else
        if y == 1
            ((x,2), (x-1,1), (x+1, 1))[rand(1:3)]
        elseif y == 200
            ((x,199), (x-1,200), (x+1, 200))[rand(1:3)]
        else
            ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x, y+1), (x,y-1))[rand(1:4)]
        end
    end
end
```

Now a function that will move a random molecule in one step a given number of `steps` is:

```
function go_sim!(molecules, steps)
    for k in 1:steps
        i = rand(axes(molecules, 1)) # in Julia 0.6 it should be: i = rand(1:length(molecules))
        @inbounds molecules[i] = move_molecule(molecules[i])
        if k % 500 == 0
        # here do entropy calculation
        end
    end
end
```

You did not provide a fully reproducible example so I stop here - but it should be easy enough to rewrite the rest of the code for entropy calculation using this data structure (actually it might be even simpler). Here is a benchmark (the performance does not depend on size of the grid nor on the number of molecules and this is an important advantage over the code that uses grid):

```
julia> molecules = [(rand(1:200), rand(1:200)) for i in 1:1000];

julia> @time go_sim!(molecules, 1e9)
 66.212943 seconds (22.64 k allocations: 1.191 MiB)
```

And you get `1e9` steps in around one minute (without entropy calculation).

What are key elements needed for a good performance:

- do not use try-catch blocks as they are very slow;
- try to avoid allocation of memory (i.e. creation of mutable objects); my code essentially does no allocations - in particular that is why I used tuples everywhere (you could use matrices in `move_molecule` function for simplicity but the performance would be around 2x worse)

Hope this helps.